# Using WriteToBigQuery FILE_LOADS in a streaming pipeline just creates a LOT of temporary tables (python SDK)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming pipeline that takes messages from pub/sub, parses them, and writes to BigQuery. The challenge is that each message goes to a different event table based on the `event` property in the message, and they are not ordered.

This means (I believe) that the `WriteToBigQuery` method cannot efficiently batch the writes, I am seeing it basically write each message one at a time, and hence it is running too slowly. I have also tried adding a 60-second window and adding a `GroupByKey`/`FlatMap` to try to reorder them, with only minimal success at speeding it up.

Using the `FILE_LOADS` method in `WriteToBigQuery` with a 60+ second triggering frequency, it APPEARS to work, sending load jobs, which then (at least sometimes) succeed and I see the data go into the correct tables. BUT, the temporary tables that were created never get deleted, so I have hundreds of tables getting created (with names like `beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_NAME_STEP_756_37417blahblahblah`)...which is obviously not sustainable.

Writing via `STREAMING_INSERTS` works fine, just slowly, this is an attempt to make it more efficient.

If anybody could help me figure out why the tables aren't getting deleted that would I think give me a working, efficient pipeline. I've tried longer triggering frequencies (up to 1 hour) but the same behavior happens.

Here is my main pipeline - again, I don't have any issues with the rest of it, just providing for context.

```
    events, non_events = (p 
        | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription = known_args.input_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
        | 'Parse JSON to Dict' >> beam.Map(lambda line: json.loads(line))
        | 'FilterOutNonEvents' >> beam.ParDo(FilterOutNonEvents()).with_outputs('MAIN_OUT', 'non_events')
    )
    
    parsed, missing_tables, _ = (events
        | 'ParseDict' >> beam.ParDo(ParseDict()).with_outputs('MAIN_OUT', 'missing_tables', 'ignore')
    )
    
    results, conversion_errors = (parsed
        | 'ConvertDataTypes' >> beam.ParDo(ConvertDataTypes()).with_outputs('MAIN_OUT', 'error_data')
    )
    
    final = (results
        | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table = lambda record: '{project}:{dataset}.{table}'.format(project = known_args.project, dataset = known_args.dataset, table = parse_event_to_dataset_name(patterns, record["event"])),
                schema = lambda tbl: {'fields':[{'name':c.split(':')[0], 'type':c.split(':')[1]} for c in schema_json[tbl.split('.')[-1]].split(',')]},
                create_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition = beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                method = 'FILE_LOADS',
                triggering_frequency = 60
        )
    )
```

The `table` arg is determined from the `event` property of the message, and the `schema` arg is simply a reformatted slice of a global variable (initially read from GCS, again, no problems with this using streaming_inserts).

Thank you to anybody that can help! Been banging my head a lot with this (I'm pretty new to beam/dataflow).

Comment: please try and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: IIRC the temp tables should be deleted. Have you been cancelling jobs? Dataflow loses its ability to delete temp tables when a job is cancelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using LOAD_FILES with multiple partitions and/or dynamic destinations the behavior should be as [follows](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/aca9099acca969dc217ab183782e5270347cd354/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.py#L800):

```py
'''
2. Multiple partitions and/or Dynamic Destinations:

    When there are multiple partitions of files destined for a single
    destination or when Dynamic Destinations are used, multiple load jobs
    need to be triggered for each partition/destination. Load Jobs are
    triggered to temporary tables, and those are later copied to the actual
    appropriate destination table. This ensures atomicity when only some
    of the load jobs would fail but not other. If any of them fails, then
    copy jobs are not triggered.
'''
```

In the [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/aca9099acca969dc217ab183782e5270347cd354/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.py#L846) also appears that after the load jobs, beam should wait for them to finish, then copy the data from the temp tables and delete them; however, it seems that when used with a streaming pipeline, it doesn't complete these steps. On my reproduction using the DirectRunner it didn't even get to the CopyJob. I suggest to report it to apache beam team [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues/).

Nonetheless, for your use case, I would reconsider using the load job approach, because you might hit the quota for [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) and [copy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#copy_jobs) jobs pretty quick; and [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#copy_jobs) might be better suited for this scenario, and probably provide a better performance on insertion than the load jobs each 60+ seconds

Comment: Tlaquetzal is correct. This is clearly a bug of the transform, and we need to fix it. Please file a bug with as much detail as you can, and we'll try to get it fixed.

Comment: Well this is at reassuring for my sanity. Thank you for confirming this! I'll go ahead and file a bug.

Comment: FYI for posterity - the streaming inserts were quite slow because the messages are unordered, thus the pipeline wasn't able to batch them very well and was basically writing one row at a time (that's why I tried to switch to FILE_LOADS in the first place).

I ended up simply writing the processed data to GCS as JSON with the table name as a prefix, then having BigQuery just read the data from there. The writes to GCS are much easier to manage in a pipeline like this. And BigQuery's ability to just sit on top of the JSON files is pretty darn useful.